# SQL Server Agent Run Python Script Issue

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I can run basic Python scripts from SQL Server Agent using the CmdExec to run a bat file pointing to my py file that prints hello world. However when trying run a file that uses the pandas module the Agent keeps coming up with the error below:

`import pandas as pd    File "C:\...\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py"<c/> line 47<c/> in <module>      raise ImportError(  ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:  dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'.  Process Exit Code 1`

The test code I am trying to execute is below:

```
import pandas as pd

lst=['a','b','c']

df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Test.csv',index=False)
```

Seeing if you had any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: Thanks I gave that a shot but looks like I already had it installed.

Comment: You probably need to install it for the user running sql server agent, or globally.

Comment: I am running the server agent on my local machine for testing and given the agent access to all folders. Not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: Checking if anyone had any possible solution?